# Overwriting list in python

Tags: python, list, overwrite

I use a list in the argument of the following function:

```
def myFunct(myList):
  print(myList) # display [0,1]
  myModifiedList = list(myList)
  myModifiedList[0]=-1
  print(myList) # display [-1,1]
  return myModifiedList
```

Of course, I'd like to display [0,1] at my second print in my function myList.
I can't find out what's wrong here, I know that everything in python works by reference. However, my function array_copy should help me to avoid the problem I'm having.

Edit: I deleted the "weird" method, but still having the problem.

Comment: You created a full copy of the list (in an inefficient manner; `copy = list(array)` or `copy = array[:]` would be faster and not require the loop); why do you think the original list will be affected when you operate on the copy?

Comment: ofc, it's append(i), not array[i]
my mistake.

It's not what I think, it's what is happening.

Comment: Indeed, `array_copy()` is just a weird reimplementation of `list()` except less efficient and with a mislead name (lists are not arrays).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your code prints out `[0, 1]` twice, and not `[0, 1]` followed by `[-1, 1]`. This isn't to say that it's flawless.

One bug is that in:

```
for i in array:
   copy.append(array[i])
```

`i` iterates over list *elements*, not *indices*. Thus, `array[i]` should read `i`.

In fact, the entire `array_copy()` function is unnecessary. You can replace:

```
myModifiedList = array_copy(myList)
```

with

```
myModifiedList = myList[:]
```

to make a (shallow) copy of the list.

Comment: I'm not here to know all the way to copy a list, my method is inefficient, but I must use it, that's all. I'm here to know why my variables myList and myModifiedList are still having the same reference.

Comment: @user1058398: I've tested the code in your question, and it does *not* behave the way you say it does.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce this behaviour using a sane method of copying the list:

```
>>> mylist = [0, 1]
>>> modified = list(mylist)
>>> modified[0] = -1
>>> print(mylist)
[0, 1]
```

Have you actually run the code you have in the question? Your copy function, as NPE points out, is inherently flawed. As always, the best answer is to not reinvent the wheel, and use the built-in method of doing this.

Comment: @user1058398 Please upload your code to http://ideone.com/ and show us the issue you are facing - I can't reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a=[0,1]
>>> print a
[0, 1]
>>> b=a
>>> b[0]=-1
>>> print a
[-1, 1]
>>> c=list(a)
>>> c[0]=3
>>> print a
[-1, 1]
>>> print c
[3, 1]
>>> print b
[-1, 1]
>>>
```

Comment: It would be good to intersperse you code sample with some explanation.